# Delete operation with foreign key reference in sqlite xamarin forms

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms

I have three models (tables) in sqlite as follows:

```
public class Program
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int ProgramId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Training
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int TrainingId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof(Program))]
    public int ProgramId { get; set; }

}

public class Instructor 
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int InstructorId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof(Program))]
    public int ProgramId { get; set; }

}
```

I have two foreign keys `ProgramId` in Training and Instructor table that reference the primary key `ProgramId` in Program table. I want to make delete operation in table Program where the `ProgramId` == 1 and I want this delete operation to be affected in the two corresponding tables `Training and Instructor` as well. How can I achieve this in sqlite using xamarin forms?

Please advise. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about cascade operations.

The standard SQLite-net package (I'm assuming you're using this one) haven't this funtionality yet, but you can achieve this using the [sqlite-net-extensions package](https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions).

The only change you would do is on your main class, where it would needed declare the relationed classes you want to do the delete on cascade. It would be changed to be like:

```
public class Program
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int ProgramId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [OneToMany(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.CascadeDelete)]
    public Training[] Trainings {get; set; }

    [OneToMany(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.CascadeDelete)]
    public Instructor[] Instructors {get; set; }
}
```

And it may do the trick.
I hope it help you.

Comment: Why this `Training[]` and `Instructor[]` ? 

and if I use `var prog = con.GetWithChildren<Program>(ProgramId);
con.Delete(prog, true);`, will it delete the records in the other two tables as well ?

Comment: 1 - This is the required notation to define cascade operations on the SQLite-net-extensions package. Please read the docummentation mentioned on the link I've posted in the answer to more information about it's notations and funtionalities; 2 - If you don't use the notation and make the change I've suggested, nothing will change for you. The `Children` part on the method's name is infered by those attributes on `Trainings` and `Instructors` properties.